# Formatting a DateTime field in Perl

Tags: perl, date-format, date-manipulation

I am trying to use a string date, and format it to output correctly as "%Y%m%d_%H%M". Everything is outputting correct except for the day. It's actually returning the next day and I have no idea as to why it is. Below is the code and output.

```
my $currentTime = strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M\n", gmtime(time));
my $hashTime    = strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M\n", gmtime(UnixDate($user->{'add_date'}, "%s")));

$self->Print($user->{'add_date'} ."\n". $currentTime . "\n" . $hashTime);
```

Output:

```
2016-12-02 20:35:43 # Date from the Database 
20161202_2046  # Current GMTime
20161203_0235  # This should be 20161202_2035?
```

How come it's outputting as 03?

Comment: Seems to be the matter of what that `UnixDate()` does?

Comment: That's from the Date::Manip package. It's supposed to convert the string into a unix timestamp.

Comment: Also, if there's a better way about doing this and Date::manip package can be used, then I'm all for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out. For people that are curious, the new code is below.

```
my $currentTime = strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M\n", gmtime(time));
my $hashTime    = UnixDate($user->{'add_date'}, "%Y%m%d_%H%M");

$self->Print($user->{'add_date'} ."\n". $currentTime . "\n" . $hashTime);
```

As you can tell, under $hashTime, when using UnixDate(), you don't need to use the strftime because it's already formatting it the way you need it.

Comment: Great, I was just getting to something like this